# Fit image to small popupbox - React.js + Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, image, bootstrap-4, package

Can someone please help me with this problem. I'm creating my personal portfolio website using react.js and bootstrap. I'm using react popupbox package but when I click on that popup using small screen, my picture is not in the middle. How can I change that? And is that even possible using only css?

Declaring popupbox code:

```
    const Portfolio = () => {
    const openPopupboxFlappyBird = () => {
    const content = (
        <>
            <img className="portfolio-image-popupbox" src= {flappyBird} alt="Flappy Bird" />
            <p>Flappy Bird game written in C#</p>
            <a className="hyper-link" onClick={() => window.open("https://github.com/zacikmareek/simpleFlappyBird", "_blank")}>Github link</a>
        </>
    )
  PopupboxManager.open({ content })
}    

    const popupboxConfigFlappyBird = {
      titleBar: {
        enable: true,
        text: "Flappy Bird"
      },
      fadeIn: true,
      fadeInSpeed: 500
    }
```

Adding image:

```
return (
        <div className="portfolio-wrapper">
            <div className="container">
                <h1 className="text-lovercase text-center py-5">.portfolio()</h1>
                <div className="image-box-wrapper row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="portfolio-image-box" onClick={openPopupboxFlappyBird}>
                        <img className="portfolio-image" src={flappyBird} alt="Flappy Bird" />
                        <div className="overflow"></div>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon className="portfolio-icon" icon={faSearchPlus} />
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <PopupboxContainer {...popupboxConfigFlappyBird} />
        </div>
    )
```

And here is my .css:

```
.portfolio-image-popubox {
  width: 45rem;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.hyper-link {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--secondary-dark);
}

.hyper-link:hover {
  color: var(--primary-red);
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .portfolio-image-popubox {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media(max-height: 640px) {
  .popupbox-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  }
  .portfolio-image-popubox {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

[This is how it looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z3iW.png)

So, is there any possibility to fit whole image to screen?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to give the image a `width:100%;` or the `w-100` bootstrap class?
If nothing happens, try adding `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` too the img tag as well.

If the img already has an 100% width, you can use the `object-fit` property, `object-fit: contain;` or `object-fit: cover;`

EDIT:

Based on some simple testing on the website that you've provided, by adding to your CSS, it should be fixed.

```
.portfolio-image-popupbox {
    width: 100%;
}
```

screenshot: https://ibb.co/pXjLwHf

Comment: Thank you, I tried everything you said but nothing changed at all.

Comment: @maiiKy are you able to temporarily put it online somewhere so I can troubleshoot it with the inspector?

Comment: I can, maybe tommorow. I'm finishing that site so after everything I can send link.

Comment: Here is link for website.. https://zacikmareek.github.io/portfolio/

Comment: @maiiKy hmm that's weird.. and if you try to add a max-heigth: 100%: to the img tag in general, will that change anything?

Comment: @maiiKy hmm that's unexpected. When I troubleshoot with Chrome inspector, it works flawlessly. what browser do you use to test on? here is screenshot from my screen https://ibb.co/pXjLwHf